# Sql update query for latitude and longitude in sqlite

Tags: ios, sql, database, xcode, sqlite

In my SQLite DB I have one table having values of latitude and longitude with every name

**products**

id , name (1000 records) , latitude(float) , longitude (float)

I have to update my DB from the class but I am little bit confused to run the query.
What I have to do is :
I have to restrict  all Lat,Long values upto four decimal places, so i need a query to update all the lat,long values so that every name must not have lat or long value greater than four decimal places.

Eg : UPDATE products set products.latitude upto .4f , products.longitude upto .4f where (Select product.latitude,product.longitude from products where latitude value >.4f or longitude value >.4f)

I am not getting the exact query to do this thing. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: latitude more than .4f means it store same values multi time

Comment: i mean that it should update the database and make the values upto  four decimal place only all the values in the database should be upto four decimal place not more than that .. how should i do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE products
SET latitude = round(latitude, 4),
    longitude = round(longitude, 4)
```

This simply updates all records because floating-point rounding errors make it unlikely that the actual number of digits can be determined.
(SQLite does not have fixed-point numbers.)